# Putting two buttons into one UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, this is driving me absolutely crazy! Been searching for hours and can't seem to figure out a solution. Any ideas how to do something like this:
[image: Groupon Screenshot]

Notice how there are two buttons inside of the tableviewcell, asnd notice how the grouped tableview has a background.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You cant make this kind of view using table view these are custom view on scrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you are thinking this is a uitableview.. you can easily implement this in uiscrolview.. just put a uiscroll view on uiview and put all the elements on it.. I have implemented several interfaces like you posted using uiscrollview... it will be very difficult to implement it in uitableview because .. when you touch on the tabs you need to open the new tab's interface and for that you have to reload the uitableview.. and manage all the interface.. which will be a pain ...

Comment: Yea that's what I was afraid of, that's a huge job to redesign it =S. Maybe we'll just do it in v2.0

Answer (score 2):

Thats basically a `UIView` on a `UIScrollView`, no `UITableView` involved.